# Как установить nginx после phpmyadmin?

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

Ставлю nginx, в нем прописываю

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name nondt.ru;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

После этого по порту 80 становится сайт и все ок, но вот с домен/phpmyadmin пропадает база, пишет Cannot GET /phpmyadmin/ . До установки nginx все работало. Как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в конфиге nginx для pma  добавить свой location, что-то вроде

```
location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

значение proxy_pass может быть другим в зависимости от используемого бэкенда